# python 2.7 requests.get() returning cookie raising TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, http-request

I'm doing a simple HTTP requests authentication vs our internal server, getting the cookie back then hitting a Cassandra RESTful server to get data. The requests.get() chokes when returning the cookie.

I have a curl script that extracts the data successfully, I'd rather work with the response JSON data in pure python.

Any clues to what I've doing wrong below? I dump the cookie, it looks fine, very similar to my curl cookie.

Craig

---

```
import requests
import rtim

# this makes the auth and gets the cookie returned, save the cookie
myAuth = requests.get(rtim.rcas_auth_url, auth=(rtim.username, rtim.password),verify=False)
print myAuth.status_code
authCookie=myAuth.headers['set-cookie']

IXhost='xInternalHostName.com:9990'
mylink='http:/%s/v1/BONDISSUE?format=JSONARRAY&issue.isin=%s' % (IXhost, 'US3133XK4V44')

# chokes on next line .... doesn't like the Cookie format
r = requests.get(mylink, cookies=authCookie)
(Pdb) next
TypeError: 'string indices must be integers, not str'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on the last line:

`r = requests.get(mylink, cookies=authCookie)`

requests assumes that the `cookies` parameter is a dictionary, but you are passing a string object `authCookie` to it.

The exception raises when requests tries to treat the string `authCookie` as a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Rikka, so I use authCookie as the value what string do I use as the dict key ?

Comment: I am not sure. What's the value of authCookie? I think authCookie itself should contain both keys and values for cookies, but in string format.